# IEEE citation style - bibtex - hyperref - first is citation number is zero

Tags: bibtex, texmaker

I don't know why but the `citations` start from `0` in the `beamer` class.
But I don't have that problem with `article class`

Here is the `MWE`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{framed}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usepackage[british,UKenglish,USenglish,english,american]{babel}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    Policy3\cite{one}. 
  \end{frame}
  \bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
  \bibliography{thesis.bib}
\end{document}

@misc{one,
  title = {{AMD} BIOS and Kernel Developer's Guide for AMD Athlon\textsuperscript{\texttrademark} 64 },
  howpublished = {\url{http://support.amd.com/us/Processor_TechDocs/26094.PDF}},
  note = {Accessed: 21/2/2013},
}
```

Result

> Policy3[0].

It should be

> Policy3[1].

Comment: I get "Policy3[1]". Don't add the `.bib` extension in the `\bibliography` command; that long set of languages boils down to `[british,american]`, but I believe that only one set of rules for one language should be used in a document.

Comment: Are you telling me that `.bib` caused the problem?

Comment: No, it's just good policy. The example compiles perfectly for me, giving [1] as expected.

Comment: no idea what the problem is.. do you suggest it might be a problem with packages conflicting?

Comment: Did you try the minimal example?

Comment: Yes. I still have the same problem.
FYI, I don't have a problem with `article` class.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7797/discussion-between-user2015933-and-egreg)

Answer (score 2):

The way to do it to set the thing in preamble of the beamer.

Try this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}    
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[text]   %This is the required line

\begin{document}    
\begin{frame}{Introduction}    
This is the introduction page. \cite{Todman2005} and  \cite{Alonzo2009} are the two references.    
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{References}    
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}    %apalike, plainnat, amsalpha, IEEEtran, ieeetr
\bibliography{beamerref}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Your references will now be listed with the numbers instead of the small logo.

Answer (score 1):

I want to provide this CW to add a minimal working example with the compiled result. The steps of the compilation are shown by the given rules of `arara`.

Some modifications I did:

- `beamer` loads a lot of packages. Some of them ar `color` and `hyperref`. So you don't need to load them.
- As mentioned in the comment the command `\bibliography` has one mandatory argument which requires the name of the `bib`-file without the extension.
- To provide a good structure I put the bibliography commands inside a frame.

Here the MWE:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: bibtex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{one,
  title = {{AMD} {BIOS} and Kernel Developer's Guide for {AMD} {Athlon}\textsuperscript{\texttrademark} 64 },
  howpublished = {\url{http://support.amd.com/us/Processor_TechDocs/26094.PDF}},
  note = {Accessed: 21/2/2013},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[british,UKenglish,USenglish,english,american]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{hyperref}%loaded by beamer
%\usepackage{color}%loaded by beamer
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{framed}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    Policy3\cite{one}. 
  \end{frame}

  \begin{frame}
   \bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
   \bibliography{\jobname}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]